# How to Remove Shipping Title Brackets () in cart summary in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

how can i remove that shipping title () in magento 2
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Override below html file under your theme:

vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/shipping.html

and remove this line from "tr" of "totals shipping excl"

It may help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: i want to remove () not all shipping method display thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this after some Implementation.

Need To Change Some Code In Magento Default Js File...

comment the below function in...

```
pub/static/frontend/magento/theme/Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/shipping.js
```

**Code-**

```
// getShippingMethodTitle: function () {
//     return '(' + this._super() + ')';
// }
```

and Return '' from this function...

```
pub\static\frontend\Magento\luma\en_US\Magento_Checkout\js\view\summary\shipping.js
```

Like This..

```
return shippingMethod ?
                '' + '' :
               '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Override below file in your theme

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/cart/totals/shipping.js
```

Change following function in return statement you can change the text or ''.

```
getShippingMethodTitle: function () {
        return '';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replate the below code on that file

> /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/Solwin/freego/Magento_Checkout/web/template/cart/totals/shipping.html

```
<tr class="totals shipping excl">
    <th class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row" data-bind="text: title + ' (' + getShippingMethodTitle() + ')'"></th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

replace that

```
<tr class="totals shipping excl">
    <th class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row" data-bind="text: title + '' + getShippingMethodTitle() + ''"></th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```